# Why is a zero score in tennis or squash called love?

Tags: etymology

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do they say “love fifteen,” in tennis?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/20733/why-do-they-say-love-fifteen-in-tennis)

What is the origin of 'love' score in tennis/squash? To be honest, I didn't not quite understand why commentators kept mentioning stuff like 15 love, 30 love, until the other player scored a point and they said 30 15.

So what is the origin of 'love'?