# Is 'deuce' (tennis) a corruption of the French phrase 'à deux de jeu'?

Tags: etymology, sports

The scoring system of tennis is somewhat arcane and the origins are not well understood. It is likely tennis derives from game played in medieval France in which a clock face was used to keep score. Points in the games were incremented in multiples of fifteen (the 'forty' call is thought simply to be short for 'forty-five', and sixty, the top score, was never called as the game ended when this score was reached). Other peculiarities of tennis scoring include the term 'deuce' and '[love](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/20733/why-do-they-say-love-fifteen-in-tennis)'.

Is 'deuce' a corruption of the French phrase 'à deux de jeu' meaning 'two points away from the (end of the) game'?

Comment: Yes, or almost. This can be answered from a dictionary, so isn't a good question here. For example, [this](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/deuce) says deuce is from *deus*, Old French for two, and can mean: "A tied score in tennis in which each player or side has 40 points, or 5 or more games, and one player or side must win 2 successive points to win the game, or 2 successive games to win the set."

Comment: This question should not be closed as general reference IMO as there isn't one that explains how *deuce* came to mean 40 all in tennis.

Comment: Another reason not to close it as general reference is that if it were, [question #20733](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/20733/why-do-they-say-love-fifteen-in-tennis) should ought to be likewise.

Comment: I still think it's General Reference. I see nothing to suggest the origin of *deuce* in tennis relates to anything other than Fr. *deux*. But it's not *two points away from game* - it's *both (**two**) players are still equally "in the game"*.

Comment: It may possibly be worth pointing out that in modern French (e.g. scoring at Roland Garros), there is a distinction between "quarante à" and "égalité", where they would both be "deuce" in English.

Answer (score 16):

The [etymology of deuce](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=deuce) goes back to the:

> late 15c., "toe 2 in dice or cards," also "a roll of 2 in dice" (1510s), from M.Fr. deus (Mod.Fr. deux), from L. duos (nom. duo) "two" (see two). Became a mild oath by 1710, about 50 years after it was first attested in the sense of "bad luck, the devil, etc.," perhaps because two was the lowest score, and probably by similarity to L. deus and related words meaning "god." Low German had der daus! in same sense 16c., which perhaps influenced the English form. Deuce coup is 1940s hot-rodder slang for "souped up two-door car," especially a 1932 Ford.

So, *deuce* means two and is used for other things besides tennis. Whether the deuce in tennis [signifies that a player needs two consecutive points](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/deuce) to win the game, or whether it means that the [two players have equal scores](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_tennis#Terminology), is contentious and best left to tennis historians. What we do know is that even though the term has its roots in French, it is not used in the French Open. They prefer *égalité* at Roland Garros :)

Comment: Françoise Bonnefoy's *Jeu de Paume: History. Réunion des musées nationaux* explains how the court was 90 feet (*pieds du roi*) with 45 feet on each side. After every point they moved 15 feet closer and served from there. If the server scored again, he or she would move another 15 feet. After 3 points could only move 10 feet closer. So *deuce* could be pre-revolution French and *égalité* could be post-revolution French.